# Предложения с уточнениями?

Tags: пунктуация

Примеры:

1. Я недавно где-то в интернете, на каком-то сайте наткнулся на одно интересное видео.
2. Я недавно в интернете, на музыкальном сайте наткнулся на одну интересную группу.

Можно или нужно "на каком-то сайте" и "на музыкальном сайте"  считать уточнениями и выделять их запятыми с двух сторон? Или здесь допустимы несколько вариантов ?

Answer (score 4):

Желательно работать с предложениями, взятыми из реальной жизни **(ваши примеры часто выглядят неестественно, надуманно)**, например:

(1) Я недавно   в Интернете  наткнулся на одно интересное видео.(1) Я недавно   на каком-то сайте  наткнулся на одно интересное видео.

(2) Я недавно в Интернете, на каком-то музыкальном сайте, наткнулся на интересную группу.

В этих случаях вариант с уточнением  предпочтительнее, так как  сайты расположены в интернете (второе обстоятельство сужает значение первого).

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ(ы) ! Но все мои примеры приводятся из обычной разговорной речи. Неужели первый пример не похож на обычный, разговорный  монолог (диалог) ?

Comment: Разговорная речь - это особый стиль речи, но и она должна быть грамотной. В первом предложении второе обстоятельство не дает вашему собеседнику никакой новой информации (и так понятно, что сайт расположен в Интернете), тогда зачем злоупотреблять его вниманием. Во втором случае область значения сужается правомерно:  вы сообщаете, в  в каком секторе Интернета (или при каких обстоятельствах)   нашли вашу интересную группу.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что пунктуация разговорной речи еще не достаточно разработана. Поэтому иногда сложно однозначно дать исчерпывающий ответ на вопрос. 
Конечно, в некоторых случаях можно ориентироваться на аналогичные конструкции книжной речи.

Так,например,если все же в ваших предложениях надо расставить знаки препинания,не меня при этом предложения, можно предложить такой вариант:

***Я недавно где-то в интернете, на каком-то сайте, наткнулся на одно интересное видео.***

***Я недавно где-то в интернете, на каком-то сайте, наткнулся на одно интересное видео. В ваших примерах уточнение.***

А вообще лучше, конечно, переделать предложения так, как советует Вера.